# Active Directory intagrated Sharepoint Site issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer, user-profile, active-directory, active-directory-import

My sharepoint site integrated with Active Directory. I changed one users name in Active Directory. But it doesn't change in sharepoint Site. How can i change users name in sharepoint designer?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Is it changed with the users profile, but just not in the content sites?  Have you run a full sync?

Comment: User's name changed only, in Active Directory. But it didn't change Sharepoint Site. Sorry, how can I run full sync? @JesusShelby

Answer (score 2):

First thing is check that you are actually syncing.  I would first visit Central Administration and under your user profile service execute a full sync and verify it runs.  There is a visual queue that it's running on the user profile service page.

After it runs you can check to see if the user name is updated.  I would also look directly and the users profile and see if the name is updated.  If it's not updated in the profile page - this is good indicator your sync may not be running properly.  You can do additional checks - such as changing other properties for another user and seeing if they propagate, but ultimately you will probably have to look at your ULS logs.  If you are at this point I recommend increasing the logging level and executing another sync than review the logs to see if there are any problems executing.

If the users profile page is updated - but the name is not updated with the sites, the issue is with a time job.  There is a quick sync time job that pushes data from the profiles into the site collections.  You can try and force run this and see if it corrects the issue - if it does you still want to see why it's not running on its own.  If it doesn't work, there may be a permission problem somewhere and you will have to go back to the ULS logs to track that down.